# Is there a browser / plugin / app to auto-reload page and show differences?

Tags: internet, browser, browser-addons

Is there a browser / plugin / app to auto-reload page and show differences between previous content and new (between 2 loads or from first one to last). The differences ideally should be shown for a few seconds and/or removed on action.

e.g. reload a news page every min and highlight new articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pagediff/

Comment: This looks nice but is there something that also reload the page every N seconds + no need to click anything to show diff?